# Having trouble passing env variable values to Azure SWA-deployed frontend-only web app

Tags: environment-variables, vite, production-environment, azure-static-web-app

My situation is the following:

Vite-based development environment. React.js frontend-only web site; deployed to Azure SWA successfully. I have included an instance of Google Maps JavaScript API as well as a user form which uses EmailJS to send an email with the form data upon submission, all without a backend. Simple enough. It all works locally, the web site shows up with Azure just fine.

What I'm having trouble with is getting my environment variables to pass through their values when I declare them in Azure's *Configuration* settings page. See below:

[image]

I have tried variable names with and without **VITE_*** prefix just to cover my bases but the result is still the same: I get **undefined** when I console log the value right before its usage in my React components. See below:

[image]

What am I doing wrong or not understanding?

Comment: Having the same issue here

Comment: I cannot for the life of me read my env vars when deploying to azure. send help. tried both adding them to the Portal and also followed:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/build-configuration?tabs=github-actions#environment-variables

no go...